# PHP - processing array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that contains DNS records and looks like this

```
Array ( [domain] => xxxx.com [record_id_+++711753] => 711753 [host_+++711753] => @ [type_+++711753] => A [priority_+++711753] => [value_+++711753] => 80.82.72.12 [record_id_+++711752] => 711752 [host_+++711752] => www [type_+++711752] => A [priority_+++711752] => [value_+++711752] => 80.82.72.12 [record_id_+++711754] => 711754 [host_+++711754] => @ [type_+++711754] => MX [priority_+++711754] => 20 [value_+++711754] => fallback.denit.net [record_id_+++711755] => 711755 [host_+++711755] => @ [type_+++711755] => MX [priority_+++711755] => 10 [value_+++711755] => ms.denit.net [record_id_+++711756] => 711756 [host_+++711756] => mail [type_+++711756] => A [priority_+++711756] => [value_+++711756] => 62.148.185.22 [record_id_+++711757] => 711757 [host_+++711757] => autodiscover [type_+++711757] => CNAME [priority_+++711757] => [value_+++711757] => autoredirect.mshex.nl [record_id_+++1148031] => 1148031 [host_+++1148031] => webmail [type_+++1148031] => CNAME [priority_+++1148031] => [value_+++1148031] => webmail.mshex.nl )
```

_+++ is a delimiter between the record_id and the type of DNS value.

I need to talk to an API to update records. It works like this (example);

```
$mdr->addParam( "command",   "dns_record_modify"           );
$mdr->addParam( "domein",    "xxx"          );
$mdr->addParam( "tld",       "com"                          );

$mdr->addParam( "record_id", "461741"                      );

$mdr->addParam( "host",      "@"                           );
$mdr->addParam( "address",   "mail2.xxx.com" );
$mdr->addParam( "priority",  "20"                          );
```

I know that I can use explode to fill the API values, domain and TLD.

However I cant seem to find a way to group the array values by record_id and fire a request per record_id that combines multiple values like host, type and priority.

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct about using the `explode()` method. IMO this is the best approach to the solution. I updated the answer because of the slight typo error and also added a working version. [See it here](https://3v4l.org/RACZE).

```
 # loop each entry
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
     # [0] - record_id
     # [1] / $value - 711753

     # check that the key isn't domain since it doesn't contain _++
    if($key != 'domain')
    {
        $mdr->addParam(explode('_+++', $key)[0], $value);
    }
    else
    {
        $mdr->addParam($key,$value);
    }
}
```

The above code snippet explodes the `_+++` out of the key to find the callback value. The `$value` then holds the corresponding data callback and then each is passed through your instanced object in the method `addParam()`.

Since the callback `domain` in your array keys does not contain the `_+++` brace, I did a check before using the `explode()` method.

Comment: `!$key = 'domain'` should be `$key != 'domain'`

Comment: thank's for pointing that out, I added a working version and updated the typo. [OP can see it here.](https://3v4l.org/RACZE) @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

To group the array values by record_ids, you could create a new, multidimensional array and use the record IDs as top-level keys. Here's an example:

```
$data = array();
$data['domain'] = 'xxxx.com';
$data['record_id_+++711753'] = 711753;
$data['host_+++711753'] = '@';
$data['type_+++711753'] = 'A';
$data['type_+++1148031'] = 'CNAME';
$data['host_+++1148031'] = 'webmail';

$sorted_data = [];

foreach($data as $key=>$val){
    $key_info = explode('_+++', $key);
    if (count($key_info) > 1){
        $record_id = $key_info[1];
        $key_name = $key_info[0];
        $sorted_data[$record_id][$key_name] = $val;
    }

}

var_dump($sorted_data);
```

Comment: domain is missing out of this, it doesn't get through the `count($key_info)` because the key doesn't include `_+++`

Comment: The question was how to group the record_ids

Comment: *and fire a request per record_id that combines multiple values like host, type and priority.*

Answer (score 0):

You could transform your data to another structure, and then produce the `$mdr->addParam` calls from that:

```
$domain = $data["domain"]; // "xxx.com"
$tld = end(explode(".", $domain)) "com"
$domain = substr($domain, count($domain)-count($tld)-1); // "xxx"

$updates = [];
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $parts = explode("_+++", $key);
    if (count($parts) != 2) continue;
    list($key, $rec) = $parts;
    if ($key == "value") $key = "address"; 
    $updates[$rec][$key] = $value;
}
```

`$updates` will be something like this:

```
Array(
    [711753] => Array (
            [record_id] => 711753
            [host] => @
            [type] => A
            [priority] => 
            [address] => 80.82.72.12
        ),
    [711752] => Array (
            [record_id] => 711752
            [host] => www
            [type] => A
            [priority] => 
            [address] => 80.82.72.12
        ),
 ...
```

Then from that, you continue:

```
foreach($updates as $update) {
    $mdr = new .... // some code to create new instance

    $mdr->addParam( "command", "dns_record_modify");
    $mdr->addParam( "domein", $domain);
    $mdr->addParam( "tld", $tld);
    foreach($update as $key => $value) {
        $mdr->addParam($key, $value);
    }
    // execute mdr ...
}
```